# store is not available in mobx-router on button press

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have a user filter component that when clicked changes the path, and sets some state. If I load my browser and visit each path individually: `/`, `/female/`, `/male` everything works as expected and the user list is displayed.

But, when I click a button and call `router.goTo(views.someRoute)` I get an error that `store.user` is undefined:

Here's my `view.js` config:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'mobx-router';

/*
 * Components
 */
import Snaproll from './Snaproll/Snaproll'
import RegistrationForm from './RegistionForm'

/*
 * Views/Router
 */
const views = {
  allUsers: new Route({
    path: '/',
    component: <Snaproll />,
    onEnter: async (route, params, store) => {
      console.log(store)
      /*
      store.user.setGender('all')
      if(!store.user.hasUsers) {
        await store.user.fetchUsers()
      }
      */
    }
  }),
  femaleUsers: new Route({
    path: '/female',
    component: <Snaproll />,
    onEnter: async (route, params, store) => {
      store.user.setGender('female')
      if(!store.user.hasUsers) {
        await store.user.fetchUsers()
      }
    }
  }),
  maleUsers: new Route({
    path: '/male',
    component: <Snaproll />,
    onEnter: async (route, params, store) => {
      store.user.setGender('male')
      if(!store.user.hasUsers) {
        await store.user.fetchUsers()
      }
    }
  }),
  register: new Route({
    path: '/register',
    component: <RegistrationForm />
  })
};

export default views;
```

In the `/` route I set a console log just to see if the store was infact available after clicking one of the following buttons. It's undefined, yet works fine when I fixing the routes manually in the address bar.

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
    import views from '../views'

    const UserFilter = ({ router }) =>
      <div className="has-text-centered">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <button onClick={() => router.goTo(views.allUsers)}>All</button>
          </li>

          <li>
            <button onClick={() => router.goTo(views.maleUsers)}>Male</button>
          </li>

          <li>
            <button onClick={() => router.goTo(views.femaleUsers)}>Female</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    export default observer(UserFilter)
```

The error I get when pressing a button is:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
    at Route._callee$ (views.js:18)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:288)
    at Generator.prototype.(/anonymous function) [as next] (https://addmysnap.local/app.js:22519:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:25)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:32
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Route.<anonymous> (asyncToGenerator.js:21)
    at Route.onEnter (views.js:17)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to pass the `store` to `goTo`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'
import views from '../views'

const UserFilter = ({ store }) =>
  <div className="has-text-centered">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button onClick={() => store.router.goTo(views.allUsers, store.router.currentView.getParamsObj, store)}>All</button>
      </li>

      <li>
        <button onClick={() => store.router.goTo(views.maleUsers, store.router.currentView.getParamsObj, store)}>Male</button>
      </li>

      <li>
        <button onClick={() => store.router.goTo(views.femaleUsers, store.router.currentView.getParamsObj , store)}>Female</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

export default observer(UserFilter)
```